# Partial Rendered incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a hidden div with a rails partial inside it. My intention is to use that hidden div as target for fancybox to open the edit form in a popup.
My partial code looks like:

```
<div style="display:none">
      <div id="inline-edit-form-<%=feed_item.id%>" class="inline-edit-form">
        <%= form_for (feed_item) do |f| %>
              <%=render :partial => 'calendars/form', :locals => { :f => f }%>
       <% end %>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Now, in Chrome, the layout is as intended and the partial is hidden initially. Fancybox manages to render this partial when its source link is clicked and things work fine. But in Firefox, the hidden DIV is not hidden by default and all controls are displayed. I checked HTML DOM structure on both Chrome and Firefox and there are huge differences.
Markup in Chrome (correct):

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="inline-edit-form-596" class="inline-edit-form">
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/calendars/596" class="edit_calendar"   d="edit_calendar_596" method="post"></form>
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
     <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
     <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
      <label for="calendar_event">Event</label><br>
      <input class="inline-edit-input" id="calendar_event" name="calendar[event]" size="30" type="text" value="Interesting event">
  </div>
```

The above markup is correct and what is expected. The shocking markup in Firefox is:

```
<div style="display: none;">
      <div class="inline-edit-form" id="inline-edit-form-598">
       </div>
</div>
<div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;"></div>
<div>
    <label for="calendar_event">Event</label><br>
    <input type="text" value="Another interesting important event" size="30"  
           name="calendar[event]" id="calendar_event" class="inline-edit-input">
</div>
```

This mark up is not only incorrect, its not even rendering the FORM tag at all. I checked and rechecked my CSS and DOM structure but Firefox simply choses to screw the layout.

Any help?

Comment: There must be some problem with nesting. Even the Chrome markup is not valid: form tag is closed right after opening tag. Could you check the raw output that the browser receives?

Comment: @heikki: You will need to scroll to the right to see the complete markup.

Comment: @ved: Please could you post the output that the browser sees? right-click > view-source

Comment: @ved: Have you set the document type to utf-8 also try setting the http header for content-type to utf8

Comment: Added- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> and removed CSS to make sure CSS is not screwing the layout. No change.

Comment: Shocking ! - from the "View Source", the DOM structure in Firefox is correct. Not sure how its rendered wrong.

Comment: @dhruvbird: Yes, the 'premature' closing tag is on the right <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/calendars/596" class="edit_calendar"   d="edit_calendar_596" method="post"></form>

Comment: @Heikki - that premature closing of form tag is not causing a problem in chrome. In the resulting form, I am able to edit the input entries.

Comment: @Ved: for me it is an indicator that something is messed in the markup the browser receives. Some browsers try to fix invalid markup and they do that in different ways. That would explain why the source looks different between Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint. There was one validation error which fixed the error. The error was that I was including  inside the table. After moving the hidden divs outside the table, the issue got resolved.